# display variable value using pug template engine inside textarea

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am getting data from mongodb and when display variable value in pug in a text-area the output of description variable `<hello my name is ahmed></hello my name is ahmed>`
the data stored in description just `hello my name is ahmed`
code in view

```
.row
    .col-md-6
          .form-group
                label(for='inputPassword3') Description
                textarea#inputPassword3.form-control(name="description", cols="30", rows="10" placeholder="Description") 
                    if user.description != undefined || user.description != null
                        #{user.description}
```

Answer (score 1):

its related to pug template engine to display value we should use this `| #{user.description}` to avoid converting variable value to tag inside text-area so the updated code will be

```
  `.row
        .col-md-6
            .form-group
                label(for='inputPassword3') Description
                textarea#inputPassword3.form-control(name="description", cols="30", rows="10" placeholder="Description") 
                    if user.description != undefined || user.description != null
                        | #{user.description}`
```